# bootstrap show/ hide div left

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, openlayers-3

I am attempting to make a site using bootstrap and I am running into a problem I can almost, but not quite solve. what I would like to do is have a div at md-2 show and hide when a button is pushed. the key is I would like the main div to be at 12 when it is hidden and at 10 to accommodate the left bar when it is present.

I am able to show and hide it with no problem but I can seem to get the main div to move accordingly. I can change its class but I cannot get the main display to "move over" to accommodate it. what happens can be viewed at the fiddle below using this jquery

```
 $('#layerbutton').click(function () {
  $(".map").toggleClass('col-md-12 col-md-10');
  $("#tree").toggle("slide");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ujcdrj46/1/

I have a feeling there is a simple solution to this but I just dont have the knowledge to figure it out. thanks for any help you can provide.

Also, please excuse the long fiddle, I couldnt get it to work any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain the `.toggleClass()` method to achieve the desired affect [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Webby2014/j1xuwenv/)

```
$('#layerbutton').on('click', function() {
   $('#map').toggleClass('col-xs-10 col-md-10').toggleClass('col-xs-12 col-md-12');
   $("#tree").toggle("slide");
});
```

**Note:** I added an `Id` attribute on the surrounding map `div` as well as including `.col-xs-*` to show this working in the Fiddle.

Comment: thank you matt. this is working well however I am running into another small problem and I am feeling lucky.the map is now shrinking in height when the layertree is present I am having difficulty recreating the problem on jsfiddle so please look at the site below http://ec2-54-186-204-72.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/demo2/OpenLayers/layertree0.html

Comment: Feel free to ask another question and I'll gladly assist. If my answer was sufficient please mark it as complete :-)

Comment: Looking as the source code of your link, you first need to restructure the html. Take a look at the [Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) grid for further clarity. Quick tips: move all your content into a single `.container`, it would also be wise to move your on page CSS into a separate file and have these references well ordered in the header of your page. Then move all your JS files to the footer, again ordering theses appropriately, this will make it much easier to work with, the problem you mention may no longer remain.

Comment: I think you may be right Matt, most of my problems most likely will come down to formatting. I will take a wander around the internet and see if I can learn a thing or two. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Anytime. Don't be afraid to ask another question on here, so long as you have tried to solve this first, you'll get many great responses and helpful feedback. Good luck with your project!